# How can I take array out of double quotes

Tags: android, json, gson

Suppose if I've a string as

```
"[{"key1": value1}, {"key2": value2}, and so on...]"
```

is there a way to convert it into array:

```
[{"key1": value1}, {"key2": value2}, and so on...]
```

Actually I've to post a JSON request in my android app which should be in the following format:

```
{
  "user_id": "5665",
  "restaurant_id": "5",
  "total_cost": "660",
  "food":[
      {"food_item_id": "50"},
      {"food_item_id": "51"}
  ]
}
```

As in the above code, I've to use the array for food key which is stuck in string which I get using the following code:

```
val gson = Gson()
val menuIds = gson.toJson(listOfMenuIds)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataclass for food_items to represent a item in the "food" array.
Then create another dataclass which has "user", "restaurant_id", ... so on... as members, including a member var foods: List

Then pass the second class to the Gson converter

Comment: So I did what you said but when I convert the class using Gson the json is stuck in string but I need to send Json object to API using (val jsonObjectRequest = object: JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,url,jsonParams, Response.Listener {...}, Response.ErrorListner{...} ...). So the jsonParams is the Json object to be sent in the said format. So the problem is still there i.e. Earlier array was stuck in string now entire object is in sring. How can I take it out in either case.